# Independence of Gamma and Beta random variables with common term

Tags: st.statistics, gamma-function

Given $\textbf{P}$ independent and identically distributed random variables, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_P \sim \Gamma(M,2c)$ how can we prove that:

$$U = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_P$$

and

$$V = \frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_P}$$

are independent?

Where $U \sim \Gamma(MP,2c)$ and $V \sim \beta(M,M(P-1))$.

Comment: so you know they are independent and are looking for a proof?

Comment: Someone states here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253607/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-ratio-between-independent-beta-and-gamma-random that they are independent but I'm not sure if that is really true.

Comment: see item 25 in http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Beta.html

Comment: Now I see. You could add that an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: this is answered in item 25 of http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Beta.html